# What are some good examples of Mixins and or Traits?

Tags: ruby, language-agnostic, mixins, traits

I was reading up on Ruby, and learned about its mixins pattern, but couldn't think of many useful mixin functionality (because I'm not used to thinking that way most likely). So I was wondering what would be good examples of useful Mixin functionality?

Thanks

Edit: A bit of background. I'm Coming from C++, and other Object languages, but my doubt here is that Ruby says it's not inheriting mixins, but I keep seeing mixins as Multiple inheritance, so I fear I'm trying to categorize them too soon into my comfort zone, and not really grok what a mixin is.

Comment: It's funny seeing the [language-agnostic] and [ruby] tags sitting right next to each other like they're best friends =)

Comment: well Ruby sparked the question, but Mixin and traits can be done in other languages, as its more of a pattern I guess

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well the usual example I think is Persistence

```
module Persistence
    def load sFileName
        puts "load code to read #{sFileName} contents into my_data"
    end

    def save sFileName
        puts "Uber code to persist #{@my_data} to #{sFileName}"
    end

end

class BrandNewClass
    include Persistence
    attr :my_data
    
    def data=(someData)
        @my_data = someData
    end
end

b = BrandNewClass.new
b.data = "My pwd"
b.save "MyFile.secret"
b.load "MyFile.secret"
```

Imagine the module is written by a Ruby ninja, which persists the state of your class to a file.
Now suppose I write a brand new class, I can reuse the functionality of persistence by mixing it in by saying `include ModuleILike`. You can even include modules at runtime. I get load and save methods for free by just mixing it in. These methods are just like the ones that you wrote yourself for your class. Code/Behavior/Functionality-reuse without inheritance!

So what you're doing is including methods to the method table for your class (not literally correct but close).

Answer (score 13):

They are usually used to add some form of standard functionality to a class, without having to redefine it all. You can probably think of them a bit like interfaces in Java, but instead of just defining a list of methods that need to be implemented, many of them will actually *be* implemented by including the module.

There are a few examples in the standard library:

Singleton - A module that can be mixed into any class to make it a singleton. The initialize method is made private, and an instance method added, which ensures that there is only ever one instance of that class in your application.

Comparable - If you include this module in a class, defining the <=> method, which compares the current instance with another object and says which is greater, is enough to provide <, <=, ==, >=, >, and between? methods.

Enumerable - By mixing in this module, and defining an **each** method, you get support for all the other related methods such as collect, inject, select, and reject. If it's also got the <=> method, then it will also support sort, min, and max.

DataMapper is also an interesting example of what can be done with a simple include statement, taking a standard class, and adding the ability to persist it to a data store.

Answer (score 3):

In ruby, the reason that Mixins aren't multiple-inheritance is that combining mixin methods is a one time thing.  This wouldn't be such a big issue, except that Ruby's modules and classes are open to modification.  This means that if you mixin a module to your class, then add a method to the module, the method *will not* be available to your class; where if you did it in the opposite order, it would.

It's like ordering an ice-cream cone.  If you get chocolate sprinkles and toffee bits as your mixins, and walk away with your cone, what kind of ice cream cone you have won't change if someone adds multicolored sprinkles to the chocolate sprinkles bin back at the ice-cream shop.  Your class, the ice cream cone, isn't modified when the mixin module, the bin of sprinkles is.  The next person to use that mixin module will see the changes.

When you `include` a module in ruby, it calls `Module#append_features` on that module, which add a copy of that module's methods to the includer one time.

Multiple inheritance, as I understand it, is more like delegation.  If your class doesn't know how to do something, it asks its parents.  In an open-class environment, a class's parents may have been modified after the class was created.

It's like a RL parent-child relationship.  Your mother might have learned how to juggle after you were born, but if someone asks you to juggle and you ask her to either: show you how (copy it when you need it) or do it for you (pure delegation), then she'll be able at that point, even though you were created before her ability to juggle was.

It's possible that you could modify a ruby module 'include' to act more like multiple inheritance by modifying `Module#append_features` to keep a list of includers, and then to update them using the `method_added` callback, but this would be a big shift from standard Ruby, and could cause major issues when working with others code.  You might be better creating a `Module#inherit` method that called `include` and handled delegation as well.

As for a real world example, `Enumerable` is awesome.  If you define `#each` and include `Enumerable` in your class, then that gives you access to a whole host of iterators, without you having to code each and every one.

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding your point, or maybe Ruby has changed since Dec. 2008, but the following code does not exhibit the "one time" behavior that you describe. In particular, note that the `Foo` instance is able to invoke the `fubb` method even though that method was added to the `Mixin` module *after* the `Foo` class mixed in the module. The example code (using semi-colons to represent line breaks): `module Mixin; def bar; puts "Mixin.bar()"; end; end; class Foo; include Mixin; end; module Mixin; def fubb; puts "Mixin.fubb()"; end; end; f = Foo.new; f.bar; f.fubb`.

Comment: If you think you're wrong, can you please edit your answer and at least add a note to read the comments? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is largely used as one might use multiple inheritance in C++ or implementing interfaces in Java/C#. I'm not sure where your experience lies, but if you have done those things before, mixins are how you would do them in Ruby. It's a systemized way of injecting functionality into classes.

Comment: Coming from C++, and others, but my doubt here is that Ruby says it's not inheriting mixins, but I keep seeing mixins as Multiple inheritance just like you say, so I fear I'm trying to categorize them too soon into my comfort zone, and not really grok what a mixin is.